# Travis-ci with tox failing on python2.6, python3.3 and pypy

Tags: python, travis-ci, tox

i just committed a seemingly uninteresting commit, updating the release notes and setup for pypi. the travis-ci build fails however running tox with py26, py33 and pypy:

https://travis-ci.org/Turbo87/aerofiles

```
1.13s$ tox -e $TOX_ENV -- --cov aerofiles --cov-report term-missing
py26 create: /home/travis/build/Turbo87/aerofiles/.tox/py26
ERROR: InterpreterNotFound: python2.6
```

i didn't change anything to the travis.yml and tox has been fixed on the 1.7.2 version:

```
language: python
python: 2.7

sudo: false

env:
  - TOX_ENV=py26
  - TOX_ENV=py27
  - TOX_ENV=py33
  - TOX_ENV=py34
  - TOX_ENV=pypy

install:
  # Install tox and flake8 style checker    
  - pip install tox==1.7.2 flake8==2.1.0

script:
  # Run the library through flake8
  - flake8 --exclude=".git,docs" --ignore=E501 .

  # Run the unit test suite
  - tox -e $TOX_ENV --  --cov aerofiles --cov-report term-missing
```

Would be great if someone could help out. I am quite new to travis-ci (and tox) and it's quite a black box at the moment.

Comment: travis-ci no longer installs py26 / py33 (end of lifed) pythons. pypy is a separate issue: https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/8081

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few week ago I was forced to change all my `.travis.yml` exactly because of the problem. See [my commit](https://github.com/phdru/ppu/commit/fc5f5464da24df370de8d7504fc7c8a2706ea229). Instead of

```
env:
  - TOXENV=py27
  - TOXENV=py34
```

write

```
matrix:
  include:
  - python: "2.7"
    env: TOXENV=py27
  - python: "3.4"
    env: TOXENV=py34
```

Comment: Do you know what was the reason for this change? Did Travis change something?

Comment: @J.G. Well, no. But I use this config since the time and everything works.